# Can I invoke a delegate/function pointer passed into a remote web service using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, delegates

Assuming you have a remote .NET web service(meaning it doesn't reside on the same server as the consuming client) what will the behavior be if you attempt to pass a delegate into the web service and invoke it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exception at best -- delegates can't cross system boundaries in that manner.

Now, you can perhaps get to the same plays doing an asynchronous call to create a continuation of sorts . . .

Comment: That was my thinking as well since the delegate is pointing to a memory location on the client that may or may not even exist on the server.